# ImportError: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: python, shared-libraries, elf

I have already looked at all of the suggested related questions, but none of them quite seem to have the answer to my problem.

I am trying to run an in-house legacy program on my 64-bit computer.  The program I am trying to run is acmegui-64bit.so (there is also a acmegui.so), so it suggests that it was designed to be run on 64 bit machines.  When I run it, I get

```
[tharpa@hpz44 bin]$ ./acmegui-64bit
:/dept/python32/lib:/usr/local/viz/notification/lib:/usr/lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dept/adapt/acme/py/acmegui.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ACME, AcmeGui
  File "/dept/adapt/acme/py/AcmeGui.py", line 10, in <module>
    import AppShell, ACME, AcmeDialog, nwrSetup, nwwsSetup, nwrMaker, cwwsMaker, \
  File "/dept/adapt/acme/py/nwrMaker.py", line 18, in <module>
    import Config, Format, ACME, AcmeDialog, BusyTkDialog, nwrText, wxRoundup
  File "/dept/adapt/acme/py/nwrText.py", line 16, in <module>
    import ACME, Decoder, Config, Format, IdsDB, Product, Setup
  File "/dept/adapt/acme/py/Decoder.py", line 12, in <module>
    import ACME, Pils, Metar, SCD, SCP, WMOHeader
  File "/dept/adapt/acme/py/Metar.py", line 6, in <module>
    import ACME, acmedcd
ImportError: /dept/adapt/acme/py/Linux/acmedcdmodule.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
[tharpa@hpz44 bin]$ ./acmegui-64bit
```

I have considered the possibility of converting acmedcdmodule.so to 64-bit.  Is this possible?  If not, how hard would it be to recreate it?

Answer (score 1):

> I have considered the possibility of converting acmedcdmodule.so to 64-bit. Is this possible?

No.

> If not, how hard would it be to recreate it?

You would have to find sources for it and rebuild it. If the original program is available as open-source, this may not be too difficult. If it's closed-source, you'd have to contact original developer(s).

Before you go too far on this, you should check whether you already have a 64-bit version of `acmedcdmodule.so` (perhaps named `acmedcdmodule-64bit.so`). If you do, fixing this may be as easy as creating a few symlinks.